# What do I have to write to make a SinonJS fakeServer call success with special parameter

Tags: javascript, jasmine, server, sinon

I am doing this ajax call:

```
$.ajax(this.apipath + "/login/refreshToken/", {
                  type: "POST",
                  async: false,
                  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem("loginToken"));
                  },
                  dataType: "json",

                  success: function (response) {
                      alert("success");
                      self.set('authenticated', true);
                      self.set('user', JSON.stringify(response.user));
                      self.set('loginToken', response.loginToken);
                      localStorage.setItem("loginToken", response.loginToken);

                      window.$.ajaxSetup({
                          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                              xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token ' + response.loginToken);
                          }
                      });
                  }
              });
```

Now I want to use Jasmine to write a test. I use SinonJS to create a fake server. I want to test, if the success function is called and if the loginToken item was set. Therefore I use this instruction:

```
server.respondWith(session.apipath + "/login/refreshToken/", [200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, JSON.stringify([{user:"asdf",loginToken:true}])]);
```

success is called but the response object does not contain a loginToken attribute. How can I make the server give the correct response object to the success function?